# Put number in range c#

Tags: c#, hash

This is widely discussed maybe, but i can't find the proper answer yet. Here is my problem i want to put a number in current range, but the number is random. I don't use

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
rand.Next(0,100);
```

the number is from `GetHashCode(),` and i have to put it in range *[0, someArray.Length);

I tried :

```
int a = 12345;
int currentIndex = a.GetHashCode();
currentIndex % someArray.Length + someArrayLength
```

but it doesn't work. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm pretty confused here... what are you trying to do again?

Comment: I think he just wants to get a random array index.

Comment: Why the `... + some.ArrayLength`?

Comment: `currentIndex % someArray.Length` is enough. But do you realize that this will cause collisions?

Comment: @NikolayKhil Only for positive inputs

Comment: I think i got the problem , because of the negative values i got negative indexes. Thanks for help.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance he is attempting to make his algorithm choose the correct [hash bucket](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144983/what-does-bucket-mean) for the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go for `(hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % modulus`. The masking ensures that the input is positive, and then the remainder operator `%` maps it into the target range.

Alternatives include:

```
result = hash % modulus;
if(result < 0)
    result += modulus;
```

and

```
result = ((hash % modulus) + modulus) % modulus
```

What unfortunately doesn't work is

```
result = Math.Abs(hash) % modulus
```

because `Math.Abs(int.MinValue)` is `int.MinValue` and thus negative. To fix this approach one could cast to `long`:

```
result = (int)(Math.Abs((long)hash)) % modulus)
```

---

All of these methods introduce a minor bias for some input ranges and modulus values, since unless the number of input values is an integral multiple of the modulus they can't be mapped to each output value with the same probability. In some contexts this can be a problem, but it's fine for hashtables.

If you mainly care about performance then the masking solution is preferable since `&` is cheap compared to `%` or branching.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle negative values is to use double-modulus.

```
int currentIndex = ((a.GetHashCode() % someArray.Length) + someArray.Length) % someArray.Length;
```

Introduce some variables into the mix:

```
int len = someArray.Length;
int currentIndex = ((a.GetHashCode() % len) + len) % len;
```

This will first make the value range from -len up to (len -1), so when you add len to it, it will range from 0 up to len*2-1, and then you use modulus again, which will put the value in the range of 0 to len-1, which is what you want.

This method will handle all valid values of `a.GetHashCode()`, no need to special-handle `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue`.

Note that this method will ensure that if you add one to the input (which is `a.GetHashCode()` in this case, so might not matter), you'll end up adding one to the output (which will wrap around to 0 when it reaches the end). Methods that uses `Math.Abs` or bitwise manipulation to ensure a positive value might not work like that for negative numbers. It depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
int currentIndex = (a.GetHashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF) % someArray.Length;
```

Note that, depending on the array length and implementation of `GetHashCode`, this may not have a random distribution.  This is especially true if you use an `Int32` as in your sample code, as `Int32.GetHashCode` just returns the integer itself, so there's no need to call `GetHashCode`.

Comment: You need to `someArray.Length` if `currentIndex < 0 if it should support negative inputs. Or mask the input of `hash & 0x7FFFFFFF`

Comment: `Abs` doesn't work for `int.MinValue` since `Abs(int.MinValue)` = `int.MinValue` < `0`

Comment: @CodesInChaos Good point - switched to using hash & 0x7FFFFFFF